# how to solve this- Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, drop-table

I'm trying to drop table and I'm getting this error :

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Some could help me please :

the statement : `DROP TABLE vehiculo`
the error  : `#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

the tables that have a relationship with vehiculo:

```
CREATE TABLE `vehiculo` (
 `numero_movil` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `numeroChasis` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
 `numeroMotor` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
 `Marca` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
 `Modelo` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `Color` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
 `Propietario_Cedula` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Cuota` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Turno_idTurno` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `estado_pago_central` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `DocumentoVehiculo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `f_numero_movil` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `f_Propietario_Cedula` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `idEstadoPapelesVehiculo` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `placa` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`numero_movil`,`Propietario_Cedula`,`Turno_idTurno`,`estado_pago_central`,`DocumentoVehiculo`,`f_numero_movil`,`f_Propietario_Cedula`,`idEstadoPapelesVehiculo`),
 UNIQUE KEY `numeroChasis_UNIQUE` (`numeroChasis`),
 UNIQUE KEY `numeroMotor_UNIQUE` (`numeroMotor`),
 KEY `fk_Vehiculo_Propietario1_idx` (`Propietario_Cedula`),
 KEY `fk_Vehiculo_Turno1_idx` (`Turno_idTurno`),
 KEY `fk_Vehiculo_estado_pago_central1_idx` (`estado_pago_central`),
 KEY `fk_Vehiculo_DocumentosVehiculo1_idx` (`DocumentoVehiculo`,`f_numero_movil`,`f_Propietario_Cedula`,`idEstadoPapelesVehiculo`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_Vehiculo_DocumentosVehiculo1` FOREIGN KEY (`DocumentoVehiculo`, `f_numero_movil`, `f_Propietario_Cedula`, `idEstadoPapelesVehiculo`) REFERENCES `documentosvehiculo` (`idDocumentoVehiculo`, `Vehiculo_numero_movil`, `Vehiculo_Propietario_Cedula`, `EstadoPapelesVehiculo_idEstadoPapelesVehiculo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_Vehiculo_estado_pago_central1` FOREIGN KEY (`estado_pago_central`) REFERENCES `estado_pago_central` (`idestado`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_Vehiculo_Turno1` FOREIGN KEY (`Turno_idTurno`) REFERENCES `turno` (`idTurno`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `vehiculo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Propietario_Cedula`) REFERENCES `propietario` (`Cedula`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci

CREATE TABLE `estadopapelesvehiculo` (  `idEstadoPapelesVehiculo` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,  `EstadoPapelesVehiculocol` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`idEstadoPapelesVehiculo`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci

CREATE TABLE `propietario` (  `Cedula` int(11) NOT NULL,  `apellidos` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,  `nombre` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,  `fechaNacimiento` date NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`Cedula`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci
```

Comment: Are there any tables that use the vehicle table as a foreign key? That's usually the problem when trying to delete a table and that error shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a table that depends on data that is inside that table, and is preventing a drop or delete of that row.  IF you find whatever tables depend on it, you can drop them, or remove the constraints, and then drop the vehicle table.