# Error 1005: Can't create table

Tags: mysql, sql

im trying to drop a table and before i had this problem [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203742/how-to-solve-this-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constrain)

and was solved succesfully but now i tried to drop the table and i got this error :

```
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'radiotaxi_final.#sql-108_28' (errno: 150)
```

the statement :

```
ALTER TABLE `RadioTaxi_Final`.`DireccionConductor` CHANGE COLUMN `Conductor_cedula` `Conductor_cedula` INT(11) NOT NULL  , 

  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_DireccionConductor_Conductor1`

  FOREIGN KEY (`Conductor_cedula` )

  REFERENCES `RadioTaxi_Final`.`Conductor` (`cedula` )

  ON DELETE NO ACTION

  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

the results :

```
SQL script execution finished: statements: 11 succeeded, 1 failed
```

the table :

```
CREATE TABLE `conductor` (  `cedula` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  `apellidos` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,  `nombres` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,  `fechaNacimiento` date NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`cedula`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci
```

Comment: 150 is a foreign key creation error. Please post the `RadioTaxi_Final.Conductor` table as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a `FOREIGN KEY`, the data types of the referenced and referencing columns must be *exactly* the same.  In your referenced table, `conductor.cedula` is of type `INT(10) UNSIGNED`.  You have attempted to create the FK on `DireccionConductor.Conductor_cedula` as `INT(11)`, implicitly `SIGNED`. modify your statement as follows to make the type match:

```
ALTER TABLE `RadioTaxi_Final`.`DireccionConductor`
  /* INT(10) UNSIGNED type matches the referenced table */
  CHANGE COLUMN `Conductor_cedula` `Conductor_cedula` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  , 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_DireccionConductor_Conductor1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Conductor_cedula` )
    REFERENCES `RadioTaxi_Final`.`Conductor` (`cedula` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Comment: thank you it worked but like this  : ALTER TABLE `RadioTaxi_Final`.`DireccionConductor`
  /* INT(10) UNSIGNED type matches the referenced table */
  CHANGE COLUMN `Conductor_cedula` `Conductor_cedula` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  , 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_DireccionConductor_Conductor1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Conductor_cedula` )
    REFERENCES `RadioTaxi_Final`.`Conductor` (`cedula` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION